# Selector syntax in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I want to get the text of any tag which contains an attribute with a value lik description in it.

for eg:-

```
<div id="id_description"> value to be fetched </div>
<span class="a-list-description-value">value to be fetched </span>
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will get the text from any Element that has an attribute containing the term "description", and store it to an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

for(Element e : doc.getAllElements()) {
    for(Attribute attribute : e.attributes()) {
        if(attribute.getValue().contains("description")) {
            results.add(e.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Using your sample HTML, `results` will contain:

```
[value to be fetched, value to be fetched]
```

Comment: is'int there any regex for it inside the document.select() tag?

Comment: i need it in elements tag!

Comment: previous answer was right, but i am asking if there is a direct way to do it.